# RTMPLite and Flash Video IO

Tags: handshake

I'm programming a videochat using rtmplite and flash VideoIO.

Now all works properly but I have a problem with the server, I don't know what is happening but after around 20 minutes of inactivity the process continues running but stop to give handshakes.

Does anyone know what could bé wrong?

Thanks

rtmplite > https://code.google.com/p/rtmplite/

flash video io > https://code.google.com/p/flash-videoio/